# How to sanitize an attribute value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, sanitize, html-escape-characters

What is the best way to sanitize an attribute value in rails? The code looks something like this:

```
<img alt="<%= h 'untrusted-data' %>" src="image-source-here" />
```

I am specifically concerned about [Rule #2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) and [Rule #3](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes) given on [owasp.net XSS prevention cheat sheet.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

> 1. Attribute Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Common Attributes
> 2. JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into JavaScript Data Values

Is html_escape method enough for the purpose? For some reason I cant use the `tag` method provided by `TagHelper` here. Using Rails 2.3.5 version.

Comment: Encoder in ruby from owasp. See encode_for_html_attr. https://github.com/thesp0nge/owasp-esapi-ruby/blob/master/lib/codec/encoder.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's good enough. (with another " though but I guess it's a typo :)

```
<img alt="<%=h untrusted %>" src="img.png" />
```

`h` will prevent `untrusted` to contain `"` and replace it by `&quot;` so that the attacker will be unable to go out of the `alt` attribute. Moreover, she will also be unable to exploit something by the `alt` attribute as no parsing is done in it.

For example, it would be different if it was in a `a`'s `href` attribute, in which case the attacker would have been able to run some javascript code when clicked even without be able to go out of the attribute. (like `javascript:alert(/XSSed/);`)

Comment: Beware though that it's not enough if untrusted data is used in an HTML attrbute that is an event handler: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=124

Comment: Yep, it was the kind of case I tried to explain with the `href` example.

Comment: Good. Here is an OWASP implementation of html attribute encoding for ruby: https://github.com/thesp0nge/owasp-esapi-ruby/blob/master/lib/codec/encoder.rb

Comment: Oh, and there is an xss playground here with escaping examples: http://www.insecurelabs.org/Task/

Comment: @thoferon Thanks, this pretty much answers my question. Thanks for pointing the typo, fixed it.

Comment: @Erlend Both the links are very useful. I am going to explore the github code here (I am assuming it will take care of the href case as well?)

Comment: For href you have to:
a) use URL encoding for things you put into a url
b) make sure the urls doesn't start with "javascript:" if you accept urls from users - this is difficult to get right because of encoding, so it's better to use a whitelist and make sure every url starts with http:// or https://

Comment: Probably `h` is applied by default in Rails now? Am I right?